# Check whether onPause state of activity is called due to screen lock

Tags: android, onpause, screen-lock

If my app is running and I press lock screen button, it will put the app in background.What is the method to check whether **onPause()** is called by screen lock?.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you have to do is check if the screen is on or not.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    boolean screenOn;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        screenOn = pm.isInteractive();
    } else {
        screenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
    }

    if (screenOn) {
        // Screen is still on, so do your thing here
    }
}
```

Comment: The if statement is because `isScreenOn()` is deprecated as of API level 20, and refers to using `isInteractive()` instead. [PowerManager.isScreenOn()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isScreenOn())

Answer (score 1):

[image: On Pause Cycle]

You Can Simply Know It By Using This Method

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
System.out.println("On Pause called");
}
```

For Keeping The Device Awake while lock screen. [Documentation.](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#screen)

Ok in your case you would need `Wake_Lock`

> To use a wake lock, the first step is to add the WAKE_LOCK permission to your application's manifest file:
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
> ```
>
> If your app includes a broadcast receiver that uses a service to do some work, you can manage your wake lock through a [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html), as described in [Using a WakefulBroadcastReceiver.](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#wakeful) This is the preferred approach. If your app doesn't follow that pattern, here is how you set a wake lock directly:
>
> ```
> PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
> Wakelock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
>     "MyWakelockTag");
> wakeLock.acquire();
> ```
>
> To release the wake lock, call [wakelock.release().](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html#release()) This releases your claim to the CPU. It's important to release a wake lock as soon as your app is finished using it to avoid draining the battery.

DO this after setting powermanager.

```
boolean screenOn;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
    screenOn = powerManager.isInteractive();
} else {
    screenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();
}

if (screenOn) {
    // Screen is still on, so do your thing here
}
```

Comment: I know that .in onpause() method i need to know that whether this onpause is called by back button or home button or lock screen

Comment: Yes whenever u move away from you activity 'onPause()' method is called.

Comment: In onpause I am performing an action.Now I want that action not to happen when onpause is caused due to screen lock.In every other case I want to perform that action.

Comment: thanks for that.Last thing...
wakelock.acquire() returns anything..?so that I can put it in if-else statement

Comment: wakelock.acquire() method releases your claim to the CPU or screen being on. The screen may turn off shortly after you release the wake lock, or it may not if there are other wake locks still held. here.     boolean screenOn;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        screenOn = pm.isInteractive();
    } else {
        screenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
    }

    if (screenOn) {
        // Screen is still on, so do your thing here
    }

Answer (score 0):

You just want to know when onPause is called? You could override the super function and add logging to the function:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  System.out.println("On Pause called");
}
```

Comment: I know that .in onpause() method i need to know that whether this onpause is called by back button or home button or lock screen